# Increase the session timeout of cloud shell in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-shell

I need to increase the session timeout of Cloud shell in GCP. When the shell is inactive for 5 mins or so, it gets timed out. How to increase the session timeout?

Answer (score 2):

Questions asking how to violate a vendor's policy are off-topic. Google's stated usage for Cloud Shell is interactive use only. You could be subject to a service limit violation and have Cloud Shell disabled.

> Warning: Violating the Terms of Service will result in Cloud Shell
> being disabled for your account. This constitutes activity that
> adversely impacts Google Cloud services, other customers' or their end
> users' use of services, or the Google network used to provide these
> services.

https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/quotas-limits#non-interactive_usage